# How to get the result of the function MULTIPLO.SUPERIOR in javascript?

Tags: javascript

in excel we have the function multiplo superior where we pass a number and it rounds to the upper multiple of the second last number - 
example:

```
10,986 ; 5 = 15 
105,32 ; 5 = 110
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Is my answer what you were looking for Mario?

Comment: precise answer, thanks @braza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `Math.ceil` function with a little bit added to it to tell it what to round to. Here is a generic function to implement it:

```js
function round(number, significance) {
  return Math.ceil(number / significance) * significance;
}

console.log(round(10.986, 5));

console.log(round(105.32, 5));
```